# An infinite dimensional limit

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, geometry, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0,1]^n} \frac{|x|}{\sqrt{n}}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
where $[0,1]^n$ is the unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X_1,X_2,...$ is an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ then the given limit is $\lim \frac 1 {\sqrt n} E(X_1^{2}+X_2^{2}+\cdots +X_n^{2})^{1/2}$. By SLLN we have $(X_1^{2}+X_2^{2}+\cdots +X_n^{2}) /n \to \int_0^{1}x^{2}dx=\frac 1 3$ a.s. and in $L^{1}$ and the result follows from this.